# Byte array - locating a character position

Tags: java, byte

I have a byte array in java. That array contains '%' symbol somewhere in it. I want to find the position of that symbol in that array. Is there any way to find this?

Thanks in Advance!

[EDIT]
I tried below code and it worked fine.

```
    byte[] b = {55,37,66};
    String s = new String(b);
    System.out.println(s.indexOf("%"));
```

I have a doubt. Is every character takes exactly one byte in java?

Comment: Is there any reason this is a byte array and not a [`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) / [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: I have updated the question with what i have tried!

Comment: @Powerlord the reason is im reading a raw resource file in Android and it returns only inputstream.

Comment: The number of bytes a character has depends on its [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). Character encodings are provided by the [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class.

Comment: @eznme No. I thought, there would be one line answer this question.

Comment: @thavan "I have a doubt. Is every character takes exactly one byte in java". No, Java uses UTF-16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct and more direct Guava solution:

```
Bytes.indexOf(byteArray, (byte) '%');
```

Comment: I looked for indexOf and didn't see it.  I guess I'm blind :-)  You get the vote

Comment: It's possible that the problem is, indeed, an encoding issue -- which would imply that you really do need to use a `String` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

using Google Guava:

```
com.google.common.primitives.Bytes.asList(byteArray).indexOf(Byte.valueOf('%'))
```

Comment: This will _not_ actually work, I think.  `'%'` will be wrapped in a `Character` object, which and `Character.valueOf('%').equals(someByteObject)` will return `false`.

Comment: I had inkling I had a type conversion issue, I think the edit should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I come from the future with some streaming and lambda stuff.
If it's just a matter of finding a byte in a byte[]:

Input:

```
byte[] bytes = {55,37,66}; 
byte findByte = '%';
```

**With streaming and lambda stuff:**

```
OptionalInt firstMatch = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length).filter(i -> bytes[i] == findByte).findFirst();
int index = firstMatch.isPresent ? firstMatch.getAsInt() : -1;
```

**Which is pretty much the same as:**

Actually, I think I still just prefer this. (e.g. and put it in some utility class).

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0 ; i < bytes.length ; i++) 
  if (bytes[i] == findByte) 
  {
    index = i;
    break;
  }
```

## EDIT

Your question is actually more about finding a character rather than finding a byte.

**What could be improved in your solution:**

```
String s = new String(bytes); // will not always give the same result

// there is an invisible 2nd argument : i.e. charset
String s = new String(bytes, charset); // default charset depends on your system.
```

So, your program may act different on different platforms.
Some charsets use 1 byte per character, others use 2, 3, ... or are irregular.
So, the size of your string may vary from platform to platform.

Secondly, some byte sequences cannot be represented as strings at all. i.e. if the charset does not have a character for the matching value.

**So, how could you improve it:**

If you just know that your byte array will always contain plain old ascii values, you could use this:

```
byte[] b = {55,37,66};
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
System.out.println(s.indexOf("%"));
```

On the other hand, if you know that your content contains UTF-8 characters, use :

```
byte[] b = {55,37,66};
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF-8);
System.out.println(s.indexOf("%"));
```

etc ...